# Существует ли функция проверки соединения PDO с БД?

Tags: php, pdo

Я видела такое решение:

```
class Db{
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dz; charset=utf8', 'root', '');
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
$con = new Db();
```

Но может есть спец функция, которую я не смогла найти?

Comment: Это бессмысленный код. Что и зачем вы хотите проверить?

Comment: @Ипатьев, я хочу написать todo list по MVC, используя PDO для общения с БД.
Сейчас пытаюсь написать метод connetc, который будет проверять соединение с БД с помощью PDO. В случае, если соединение установлено возвращать true, в обратном случае создавать экземпляр PDO

Comment: @Ипатьев, есть у PDO что-то вроде ping() для mysqli?

mysqli::ping -- mysqli_ping — Проверяет работоспособность соединения или пытается переподключиться, если соединение разорвано

Comment: Во-первых, для такого метода не надо проверять соединение. Достаточно проверить переменную, в которой оно лежит. Во-вторых, непонятно, почему возвращается true, а не экземпляр. И в-третьих, это в принципе бессмысленный код. Надо просто в самом начале соединиться, и дальше уже использовать полученное соединение.

Comment: Зачем вам пинг? У вас хоть раз был такой случай, что соединение было-было, а потом вдруг пропало?

Comment: Пока задавала вопрос, тоже была такая мысль, что можно просто переменную проверять) спасибо)
Решила по видео из ютуба сделать todo MVC, но там исп mysqli, а я хотела PDO использовать, отсюда такой вопрос.

Comment: Все эти видео обычно ужас, летящий на крыльях ночи.  Поэтому вы пожалуйста пишите сюда ключевые моменты. А лучше целиком код, который получится. На русском как-то непонятно, можно ли это, но на английском есть специальный сайт, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: И я очень рекомендую не писать никаких обёрток над ПДО. потому что это *уже* класс, и не самый плохой. Надо сначала научиться им пользоваться нормально, а потом уже писать обёртки

Comment: В общем, я закрываю этот вопрос как дубликат, но вам для вашего туду листа это точно не пригодится

Comment: PDO - это же способ подключения и общения с БД, а MVC - это паттерн построения архитектуры приложения. Поэтому экземпляр PDO решила делать в  классе DB, который будет отвечать за общение с БД. На моих курсах так учили. Вы по-другому с PDO работаете?
А код, который я вставила в описание - типичное решение из интернета:D

Comment: "типичные решения из интернета" - это типично треш и угар, написанный полуголыми индусами в перерыве между возделыванием рисовых полей, и потом переписанный полуграмотными русскими в целях самоутверждения. Поэтому "из интернета" надо брать с очень большой осторожностью.Это первое.

Comment: Второе. PDO - это не "способ подключения к БД". Это класс для работы с БД. И у вас получается рекурсия: "Поэтому экземпляр класа для работы с БД решила делать в классе БД, который будет отвечать за общение с БД" :)

Comment: Я работаю с PDO через очень маленькую и простую обёртку. Но для "моего первого MVC" приложения прекрасно подойдет и чистый ПДО, и я настоятельно рекомендую сделать именно так. Запихивая ПДО в свой класс, новички тут же отпиливают 90% богатейшего функционала, и теряют шанс с ним познакомиться. Поскольку эта дискуссия уже переросла рамки вопроса, я предлагаю перенести её в чат.